# ¿Cómo puedo sumar las columnas de una lista de listas?

Tags: python, lista

El ejercicio consiste en pasar una lista de números a binario y después sumar columna a columna el resultado y pasarlo a binario otra vez.

Por ejemplo:

```
>>> sumas([5, 0, 2, 7, 3])
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

He conseguido crear una lista formada por las listas de binarios de los números dados, pero ahora no consigo sumar las columnas, es decir la posición 0 de la fila 0 con la posición 0 de la fila 1... He probado distintos métodos pero siempre me da algún tipo de error.

Este es el código que estoy utilizando:

```py
def decimalToBinario(n):
    """
    Función auxiliar con la que se obtiene la representación binaria
    de un número en base 2
    """
    if (n <= 0):
        return ['0']
    binario = ''
    while (n > 0):
        resto = int(n % 2)
        n = int( n / 2)
        binario = str(resto) + binario
    return list(binario)


def completarBinario(binario, longitudFinal):
    """
    Función auxiliar con la que se completa la lista con valores nulos
    hasta que alcanza la longitud especificada
    """
    binario = list(binario)
    if (len(binario) < longitudFinal):
        while len(binario) < longitudFinal:
            binario.extend(['0'])
            len(binario) + 1
        return binario


def convertir_montones(listaMontones):
    """
    Función auxiliar para convertir la lista de montones en una lista de
    representaciones binarias de la lista de montones
    """
    for i in range(len(listaMontones)):
        listaMontones[i] = completarBinario(decimalToBinario(listaMontones[i]), 5)
        i = i + 1
    return list(listaMontones)


def sumas(listaMontones):
    listaMontones = convertir_montones(listaMontones)
    listaMontones = []
    for x in range(0, 6):
        sumColumna = 0
        for y in range(0, 6):
            sumColumna = sumColumna + int(listaMontones[y][x])
    return sumColumna
```

Ejemplo:

```
>>> print(sumas([5,0,2,7,3])
[0,0,0,1,1]
```

La función primero transforma las listas (listaMontones) en una lista formada por las listas de los números binarios correspondientes con la . Después la función convertir_montones que transforma la listaMontones en la lista de listas de bianrios utilizando la función decimalToBinario y la función completarBinario para que todos tengan la misma longitud(`len=5`). Finalmente la función sumas tendría que sumar las columnas ( es decir sumar la posición 0 de la fila 0 con la posición 0 de la lista 1...) y transformar esa suma a binario.

Con la funcion que utilizo me da un

> TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Comment: Hola Paula, podrías crear un dataframe de ejemplo en código para que podamos copiar y pegar, y sea más fácil ayudarte. Tambien ayudaría a mejorar la pregunta que añadieses después el resultado que esperas  (resultado esperado) realizando la operación con dicho DataFrame.

Comment: Bienvenida, @Paula. Comprueba si el código que has puesto está correctamente identado. La función `completarBinario` tiene el `return` dentro del _bloque if_, por lo que hay casos que no va a devolver nada. La idea es que el código sirva para que podamos reproducir tu problema y centrar mejor la solución a darte.

Comment: Buenos días, @ChemaCortes, la función completarBinario, no me devuelve ningún tipo de error cuando la pruebo. Es al utilizar la función sumas donde me de distintos tipos de errores dependiendo del cuerpo de instrucciones que use( ya que he probado distintos métodos). Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Hay un error en tu función `completarBinario`, estás usando `extend` para añadir ceros a tu binario y completarlo hasta cierta longitud. Pero estás añadiendo los ceros al final del binario, cuando deberían estar al principio.

Es decir, 2 te lo convierte en 10000, pero debería convertirlo en 00010. Para conseguir esto usa `binario.insert(0, '0')` (inserta en el índice 0 el carácter '0').

En el código que pasas, tienes también esto:

```py
listaMontones = convertir_montones(listaMontones)
listaMontones = []
```

Luego estás accediendo a `listaMontones[y][x]` cuando has asignado `listaMontones` con una lista vacía, así que ahí dará `IndexError: list index out of range`

El primer `for` anidado de `sumas`, debería iterar entre 0 y `len(listaMontones[0])`, para asegurar que no nos salimos del número de dígitos de cada binario.

El segundo `for` anidado de `sumas`, debería iterar entre 0 y `len(listaMontones)`, para poder recibir un número variable de números.

También necesitas una lógica de suma de bits, porque en decimal 1 + 1 = 2, pero en binario 1 + 1 = 10, y en ese caso, si no entiendo mal, quieres que el resultado sea 0, no 1, ni 2.

Esto se traduce en devolver 1 si ambos números son distintos (un XOR/or exclusivo):

```py
def sumar_digito_binario(dig1, dig2):
    return 1 if (dig1 and not dig2) or (not dig1 and dig2)
    # Es equivalente a esto:
    # return 1 if ((dig1 == 1) and (dig2 == 0)) or ((dig1 == 0) and (dig2 == 1)) else 0
```

Según eso:

| dig1 | dig2 | XOR(dig1, dig2) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |

Al final, te sale este código, que creo que hace lo que quieres (he cambiado solo lo que he indicado arriba, lo demás es código tuyo):

```py
def decimalToBinario(n):
    """
    Función auxiliar con la que se obtiene la representación binaria
    de un número en base 2
    """
    if (n <= 0):
        return ['0']
    binario = ''
    while (n > 0):
        resto = int(n % 2)
        n = int( n / 2)
        binario = str(resto) + binario
    return list(binario)


def completarBinario(binario, longitudFinal):
    """
    Función auxiliar con la que se completa la lista con valores nulos
    hasta que alcanza la longitud especificada
    """
    binario = list(binario)
    if (len(binario) < longitudFinal):
        while len(binario) < longitudFinal:
            binario.insert(0, '0')
            len(binario) + 1
        return binario


def convertir_montones(listaMontones):
    """
    Función auxiliar para convertir la lista de montones en una lista de
    representaciones binarias de la lista de montones
    """
    for i in range(len(listaMontones)):
        listaMontones[i] = completarBinario(decimalToBinario(listaMontones[i]), 5)
        i = i + 1
    return list(listaMontones)


def sumar_digito_binario(dig1, dig2):
    return 1 if (dig1 and not dig2) or (not dig1 and dig2) else 0


def sumas(listaMontones):
    listaMontones = convertir_montones(listaMontones)
    sumColumna = []
    for x in range(len(listaMontones[0])):
        sumColumna.append(0)
        for y in range(len(listaMontones)):
            sumColumna[x] = sumar_digito_binario(sumColumna[x], int(listaMontones[y][x]))

    return sumColumna
```

---

Y estos resultados:

```
print(sumas([2, 3])) # Muestra [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
print(sumas([5, 0, 2, 7, 3])) # Muestra [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Comprobamos eso?

```
bin(2) = 10
bin(3) = 11
suma   = 01
```

```
bin(5) = 101
bin(0) = 000
bin(2) = 010
bin(7) = 111
bin(3) = 011
suma   = 001
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, la función me sale perfecta.

Comment: Me alegro. Deberías marcar la respuesta como correcta entonces :-)