# ¿Cómo puedo calcular la posición de la primera lista cuya representación binaria tiene un 1 en la posición dada en pyhton?

Tags: python, lista, binario

Tengo una función que convierte una lista de número en una lista de sus respectivas representaciones binarias; la he denominado `decimalToBinario`.

Después con la función `completar_binario` transformo las representaciones binarias para que todas tengan la misma longitud.

Con la función `cifra_i_base2` puedo calcular el dígito en la posición
indicada de la representación binaria del número dado.

Necesito una función que sea capaz de calcular la posición de la primera lista cuya representación binaria tiene un 1 en la posición dada. Es decir, de una lista de número primero tengo que transformalos a binario, después tengo que recorre la lista para ver cual es la primera representación de los binarios que tiene un 1 en la posición dada.

Mi código es el siguiente :

```
def decimalToBinario(n):
    """
    Función auxiliar con la que se obtiene la representación binaria
    de un número en base 2
    """
    if (n <= 0):
        return ['0']
    binario = ''
    while (n > 0):
        resto = int(n % 2)
        n = int( n / 2)
        binario = str(resto) + binario
    return list(binario)


def completarBinario(binario, longitudFinal):
    """
    Función auxiliar con la que se completa la lista con valores nulos
    hasta que alcanza la longitud especificada
    """
    binario = list(binario)
    if (len(binario) < longitudFinal):
        while len(binario) < longitudFinal:
            binario.extend(['0'])
            len(binario) + 1
        return binario

def cifra_i_base2(n,posicionDigito):            
    """
    Función que calcula el dígito de la representación binaria en la posición indicada
    """
    n=completarBinario(decimalToBinario(n),5)
    digito=(n[posicionDigito])
    if posicionDigito in range(0,len(n)):
        return digito
    else:
        return [0]
 def buscarMonton(listaMontones,posicion): # Función auxiliar
   for elementos in listaMontones:
       if (cifra_i_base2(elementos,posicion)) == 1:        
           return listaMontones[elementos]
   return listaMontones[elementos]
```

Ejemplos:

```
print (buscarMonton([5,0,1,3,0],2))
0
```

Con este código la función me devuelve es último elemento de la listas y no se como arreglarlo porque las otras funciones funcionan bien, pero la que me falla es la de bucarMontones

Comment: +1 por una pregunta bien formulado.

Comment: Entiendo que viene de tu anterior pregunta: [¿Cómo puedo sumar las columnas de una lista de listas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/424923/83). Iría bien presentar un [mcve]. Es decir, ejemplos buenos, ejemplos de lo que te sale actualmente y por qué no son correctos.

Answer (score 3):

Modifique ligeramente la función `decimalToBinario` para que retorne un arreglo de digitos (no caracteres) del largo indicado por `longitudFinal`. También elimine el uso de cadenas y concatenación. En su lugar, simplemente agregue elementos a la lista de digitos binarios.

La lista `binario` es la representación binaria del número. Hay que anteponerle los ceros para completar el largo requerido. Los ceros que faltan los da `longitudFinal`, y la expresión

```
[0] * longitudFinal
```

genera una lista con la cantidad de ceros requeridas.

Luego solo queda contatenar ambas listas.

```
def decimalToBinario(n, longitudFinal):
    """
    Función auxiliar con la que se obtiene la representación binaria
    de un número en base 2
    """
    binario = []
    if n > 0:
        while (n > 0):
            longitudFinal -= 1
            resto = int(n % 2)
            n = int(n / 2)
            binario.append(resto)

    pre = [0] * longitudFinal
    pre.extend(binario)
    return pre
```

En la función `buscarMonton` hay un problema con esta línea:

```
return listaMontones[elementos]
```

que debería ser

```
return elementos
```

Con la línea original estás usando el valor de la lista (5, por ejemplo), como índice de la misma lista. Claro, `listaMontones[5]` no existe.

Si no encuentra un elemento, la función debe retornar algo no numérico, para poder identificar que no se encontró lo buscado. En este caso, retornare `None`

```
def buscarMonton(listaMontones, posicion):  # Función auxiliar
    for elemento in listaMontones:
        n = decimalToBinario(elemento, 5)
        if n[posicion] == 1:
            return elemento
    return None
```

Probando

```
print("Pruebas:")
for i in range(5):
    elemento = buscarMonton([5, 0, 1, 3, 0], i)
    binario = decimalToBinario(elemento, 5) if elemento else ''
    print(f"Primer elemento con 1 en la posicion {i} es {elemento} {binario}")
```

produce:

```
Pruebas:
Primer elemento con 1 en la posicion 0 es None 
Primer elemento con 1 en la posicion 1 es None 
Primer elemento con 1 en la posicion 2 es 5 [0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
Primer elemento con 1 en la posicion 3 es 3 [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
Primer elemento con 1 en la posicion 4 es 5 [0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Gracias, funciona genail

Answer (score 0):

puedes simplificar la funcion `cifra_i_base2(n,posicionDigito)` en esto

```py
def cifra_i_base2(n,posicionDigito):
    return n.pop(posicionDigito)
```

La funcion `pop(indice)` recibe un indice de un arreglo y te devuelve el valor de dicho indice.

Comment: Ojo que `pop` remueve el elemento de la lista. No sé si sea significativo en este caso, pero valdría aclararlo.

Comment: Perdon, olvide de aclarar eso.

Comment: Hola @SebastianSoto, necesito ayuda con la función buscarMontones ya que esta me devuelve el último elemento de la lista pero me debería devolver la posición de la primera lista cuya representación binaria tiene un 1 en la posición dada. Es decir, de una lista de número primero tengo que transformalos a binario, después tengo que recorre la lista para ver cual es la primera representación de los binarios que tiene un 1 en la posición dada.